# jQuery function not passing on finish countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm using this plugin: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/ It counts the time from a date. Everything is working fine except the `.on('finish.countdown', function(event)` when I console.log I get nothing. So it seems that it doesnt work. Can someone tell me why ? Maybe can fix ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tr').each(function() {
    var inputDate = new Date($(this).find('.count').text());
    var timeProduct = $(this).find('.timeProduct');
    timeProduct.html('Aktyvus');
    inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);

    $(this).find('.clock').countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
      $(this).text(event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek'));
    }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
      var timeProduct = $(".timeProduct");
      timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
      timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
      timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
      console.log('labas');
    });

  });
});
```

**EDIT**

This is JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mo6fhum5/

You can see that when timer hits 0 it's still says `aktyvus`

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: could you add the html code or jsfiddle version to help you?

Comment: You fiddle is not working. All times are `NaN` (Not a Number)

Comment: What do you mean ? @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4ptje2y0/)

```
$('table tr').each(function(index) {
  var inputDate = new Date($(this).find('.count').text());
  var timeProduct = $(this).find('.timeProduct');
  inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);
  timeProduct.html(inputDate.getTime()>new Date().getTime()?'Aktyvus':"Pasibaigė");

  console.log(inputDate)
  $(this).find('.clock').countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
    $parent=$(this).closest("tr");
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek'));
  }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    console.log("done");
    var timeProduct = $parent.find(".timeProduct");
    timeProduct.removeClass("label label-success");
    timeProduct.addClass('label label-danger');
    timeProduct.html("Pasibaigė");
  });
});
```

Active:

[image]

Done
[image]

Comment: Works for me. I have to change the last date and time to a short interval. See pictures

Comment: But you need at least one to RUN - it will not run when the time is in the past

Comment: Can u show me your fiddle where it says `Pasibaigė` ?

Comment: Just change the time in product 3 to 2 minutes ago and 1 minute from now

Comment: Okay, I see now. I'll try with my webpage now

Comment: See update. It shows DONE when the page loads with a date in the past